# When I click on hyperlink I am getting page not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5. When I click on edit button I am getting error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.". Really strange thing

**web.php**

```
/* View booking history */
    Route::get('/booking/history', 'BookingController@index')->name('booking.history');

    /* Download voucher */
    Route::post('/booking/history/voucher/download', 'BookingController@downloadVoucher')->name('booking.history.voucher.download');

    /* Delete cancelled booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/delete/cancelled/booking', 'BookingController@destroyCancelledBooking')->name('booking.history.delete.cancelled.booking');

    /* Delete waiting prepay booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/delete/waiting/prepay', 'BookingController@destroyWaitingPrepayBooking')->name('booking.history.delete.waiting.prepay');

    /* Delete approved inquiry booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/delete/approved/inquiry', 'BookingController@destroyApprovedInquiry')->name('booking.history.delete.approved.inquiry');

    /* Delete waiting inquiry booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/delete/waiting/inquiry', 'BookingController@destroyWaitingInquiry')->name('booking.history.delete.waiting.inquiry');

    /* Delete rejected inquiry booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/delete/rejected/inquiry', 'BookingController@destroyRejectedInquiry')->name('booking.history.delete.rejected.inquiry');

    /* Cancel booking */
    Route::post('/booking/history/cancel', 'BookingController@cancelBooking')->name('booking.history.cancel');

    /* Edit booking history */
    Route::get('/edit/booking/history/{id]', 'BookingController@edit')->name('edit.booking.history');

    /* Update booking history */
    Route::post('/edit/booking/history/{id]', 'BookingController@update')->name('update.booking.history');
```

**booking.blade.php**

```
<a href="/edit/booking/history/{{ $booking->_id }}" class="btn btn-list-history" style="color: inherit;">{{ __('bookingHistory.editBooking') }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a>
```

BookingController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
  dd($id);
}
```

Comment: `{id]` should be `{id}` in your routes

Comment: @kerbholz, Thank you. It is working.

Comment: agree with @kerbholz... in addition you've gone to the trouble of naming your route, why not use it in your template? `<a href="{{ route('edit.booking.history', $booking->_id) }}" class="btn btn-list-history"...`. so later, if you need to change the path, you'll only need to update your routes and not the templates as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{}` brackets for parameter segment in your route.

Like this:

```
Route::get('/edit/booking/history/{id}'
```